# Adding value labels to bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to get a bar plot with value labels on each bar. I have searched all over but can't get this done. My df is the one below.

```
Pillar                       % 
Exercise                    19.4
Meaningful Activity         19.4
Sleep                        7.7
Nutrition                   22.9
Community                   16.2
Stress Management           23.9
```

My code so far is

```
df_plot.plot(x ='Pillar', y='%', kind = 'bar')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ax.bar_label`:

```
ax = df.plot(x='Pillar', y='%', kind='bar', legend=False, rot=0)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: bar with values]